# So, what do I do with the output of yum check?

Tags: yum

When I run yum check (or try to use yum to update my system generally), I get the following:

```
# yum check
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
krb5-devel-1.10.2-12.fc17.x86_64 has missing requires of keyutils-libs-devel
krb5-devel-1.10.2-12.fc17.x86_64 has missing requires of libselinux-devel
libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with libdb-5.2.36-5.fc17.x86_64
1:openssl-1.0.0k-1.fc17.x86_64 is obsoleted by 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1c-7.fc18.x86_64
1:openssl-1.0.1c-7.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:openssl-1.0.0k-1.fc17.x86_64
rpm-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-build-libs-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-build-libs-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-libs-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-libs-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-python-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-python-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
sqlite-3.7.11-3.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with sqlite-3.7.11-2.fc17.x86_64
Error: check all
```

With the duplicates in particular, if I try to uninstall them, a bunch of other packages will be uninstalled (for each package on either side of the "is a duplicate with"). How do I resolve that?

As to the missing requires, I *assume* I can install the missing requires.

Update: I was able to resolve some of these errors:

1. The sqlite duplicate was resolved by `# yum reinstall sqlite-3.7.11-3.fc17.x86_64`
2. The missing requires were resolved just by installing them with yum.
3. Attempting to solve the openssl issues with reinstall did not work:

   ```
   # yum reinstall openssl
   Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
   Setting up Reinstall Process
   Resolving Dependencies
   --> Running transaction check
   ---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.0k-1.fc17 will be reinstalled
   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
   Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
      cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
      pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

    1. You have an upgrade for openssl which is missing some
       dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
       solve this by installing an older version of openssl of the
       different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
       yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
       requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
       --exclude openssl.otherarch ... this should give you an error
       message showing the root cause of the problem.

    2. You have multiple architectures of openssl installed, but
       yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
       If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
       can remove the one with the missing update and everything
       will work.

    3. You have duplicate versions of openssl installed already.
       You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

      ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
      this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
      do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
      much more problems).

      Protected multilib versions: 1:openssl-1.0.0k-1.fc17.x86_64 != 1:openssl-1.0.1c-7.fc18.x86_64
   ```

Update: Here's what `rpm -qa --dupes` emits:

```
# rpm -qa --dupes
gpg-pubkey.(none)
kernel-devel.x86_64
kernel.x86_64
libdb.x86_64
openssl.x86_64
rpm-build-libs.x86_64
rpm-libs.x86_64
rpm-python.x86_64
rpm.x86_64
```

More update:

```
# rpm -q --qf '%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}\n' libdb openssl rpm{,-{libs,python,build-libs}}
libdb-5.2.36-5.fc17.x86_64
libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1c-7.fc18.x86_64
openssl-1.0.0k-1.fc17.x86_64
rpm-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64
rpm-libs-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-libs-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64
rpm-python-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64
rpm-python-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-build-libs-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64
rpm-build-libs-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
```

Comment: What does `rpm -qa --dupes` spit out at this point?

Comment: @EtanReisner Added in update.

Comment: Bah. I was hoping for version information there. yum is clearly confused about the multilib status of openssl but that's probably not a big deal. What does `rpm -q --qf '%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}\n' libdb openssl rpm{,-{libs,python,build-libs}}` say?

Comment: @EtanReisner I added that too

Comment: You should try to figure out which of those packages is actually installed (which version of the files is actually on disk). Are you running Fedora 17 or 18? Which packages scream when you run `rpm -V` on them (use the full version output to be sure you are testing the one you think you are)? Does `package-cleanup --problems` list anything? You might also want to try `package-cleanup --cleandupes`. It sounds like it might be useful here.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418301/yum-error-package-is-a-duplicate-with